# How to run different tasks on 2 nodes in one job

Tags: task, host, rundeck

I need to run different jobs on 2 nodes in one job.
    #!/bin/bash

```
#Create the following folders:
mkdir -p /shared_folder/files/Source
mkdir -p /shared_folder/files/Target


#Generate the backups
#Under Source execute the following command:
cp -r /local/folder /shared_folder/files/Source

#Under Target execute the following command:
cp -r /local/folder /shared_folder/files/Target

#Delete all Target mobile configurations:
#Under Target execute the following command:
rm /local/folder/*.*

#Copy the mobile configurations from Source to Target:
#Under Target execute the following command:
cp  /shared_folder/files/Source/*.* /local/folder/

Restart Tomcat Service in Target:
Under Target execute the following command:
/sbin/service tomcat restart
```

Below is my reference job which uses ${option.NodeFilter1} and ${option.NodeFilter2} to pass node names to the actual 2 jobs.

I don't know if I have to run this reference job locally and these 2 actuall jobs to be pushed to the machines or this reference job should also be pushed to the actuall machines. ?

```
After suggestion I've created this job reference. It references 2 actual jobs.
- id: 98e41ff6-93e3-455a-9744-29bb6e8aae27
  project: SecureCloud
  loglevel: INFO
  sequence:
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
    commands:
    - jobref:
        group: apps
        name: Synchronize mobile configurations Source
        args: -Nodefilter1 ${option.NodeFilter1}
        nodeStep: 'true'
        nodefilters:
          filter: ${option.NodeFilter1}
      description: Source
    - jobref:
        group: apps
        name: Synchronize mobile configurations Destination
        args: -NodeFilter2 ${option.NodeFilter2}
        nodeStep: 'true'
        nodefilters:
         filter: ${option.NodeFilter2}
      description: Destination
  description: ''
  name: Synchronize mobile configurations Master
  uuid: 98e41ff6-93e3-455a-9744-29bb6e8aae27
  group: apps
 options:
    NodeFilter1:
      required: true
    NodeFilter2:
      required: true
```

This is one of 2 actuall jobs

```
- id: 47b65475-f14b-4e5e-8d4f-aa9bb3c8e2b6
  project: SecureCloud
  loglevel: INFO
  sequence:
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
    commands:
    - script: |
        #!/bin/bash

        touch /home/user/source-@option.NodeFilter1@



      scriptInterpreter: sudo
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
  description: Synchronize mobile configurations
  name: Synchronize mobile configurations Source
  uuid: 47b65475-f14b-4e5e-8d4f-aa9bb3c8e2b6
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      threadcount: 2
      keepgoing: true
      excludePrecedence: false
      rankOrder: ascending
    filter: ${option.NodeFilter1}
  group: apps
  options:
    NodeFilter1:
      required: true
      description: Source Node
```

I get this error while trying to run this configuration:

Option input was not valid for [apps/Synchronize mobile configurations Source]: Option 'NodeFilter1' is required.
13:50:58            Execution failed: 637: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [c000lrdp01na01.na01.mstrci.com: InvalidOptions: Invalid options: [NodeFilter1]]}, Node failures: {c000lrdp01na01.na01.mstrci.com=[InvalidOptions: Invalid options: [NodeFilter1]]}, flow control: Continue, status: failed

Answer (score 2):

You can create two jobs, one each to perform the appropriate task on the separate nodes.  Then create another job which executes both of those two jobs via the Job Reference feature.  Make sure not to set a node filter in the third job.

Comment: Can I pass nodenames taken from nodefilter from this reference job to these 2 jobs ? I am asking because these nodes on which it will be runing will be changing.

Comment: I've created this reference job.

Comment: Make sure the capitalization is correct, i see in the first jobref you have `args: -Nodefilter1 ${option.NodeFilter1}`, but your option is named `NodeFilter1` (`F` not `f`)